# How does one reference the result of a call block in an emacs org file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, literate-programming, org-babel

I'm using emacs org mode for reproducible research.  I'm having trouble chaining the results of calls to code blocks.  As a minimal example of what I'm trying to do:

```
* Functions
#+name: f1
#+begin_src elisp :var x=7
  (+ x x)
#+end_src

#+name: f2
#+begin_src elisp :var x=7
  (+ x 2)
#+end_src

* Data
#+name: intermediate
#+call: f1(x=5)

#+RESULTS: intermediate
: 10

#+call: f2(x=intermediate)
```

When I call `f2`, it fails because `x` is `nil`.  If I remove the name from the call on `f1`, then f2 works, but the results don't stay in sync if I change the parameters for `f1`.

How do I tell org mode that I want to see the results of the function call without needing to manually rename the results every time they are calculated?

Comment: On org-mode 8.2.6 your example correctly gives 10 and 12 as results when exporting.

Comment: I'm also running org-mode 8.2.6 in Emacs 24.3.1. If I copy verbatim what is listed above into an empty emacs org buffer, exporting to html fails with the message 'Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, "nil"'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using [Noweb](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/) reference syntax in your calculations under the `Data` heading:

```
* Functions
...

* Data
#+name: intermediate
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :noweb yes
<<f1(x=5)>>
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :noweb yes
<<f2(x=intermediate)>>
#+END_SRC
```

From the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-reference-syntax.html) (emphasis mine):

> The "noweb" ... Literate Programming system allows named blocks of code to be referenced by using the familiar Noweb syntax:

```
<<code-block-name>>
```

> When a code block is tangled or evaluated, whether or not "noweb" references are expanded depends upon the value of the `:noweb` header argument. If `:noweb` yes, then a Noweb reference is expanded before evaluation. [...]
>
> It is possible to include the **results** of a code block rather than the body. This is done by appending parentheses to the code block name which may optionally contain arguments to the code block as shown below.

```
<<code-block-name(optional arguments)>>
```

With this setup you can change the value of `x` that you are passing to `f1` and re-export/re-evaluate successfully without having to modify anything else.